# Complex path Integral (Form: $\frac{e^{iz}}{p(z)}$ ) over non-closed curve (Here: Open semicircle)

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

I have the following problem given:

> let $\gamma$ be an open upper semicircle with Radius $R$, $\gamma(t) = Re^{it}, t\in[0,\pi]$
>
> Calculate the Integral $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{(z-3i)^2(z+i)}dz$

This obviously leads to the problem, that I'm going to have an exponential function inside an exponential function, if I just use the given path $\gamma$ and Integrate normally.

As this is also an open curve, instead of a closed curve, I'm unsure how I could apply Residue Theory here, nor am I sure that this is actually how to solve the problem, as the next problem given is to calculate the Residues, so either the point is that I just need one Residue (of $z = 3i$), or none at all.

In search of an Answer I also stumbled upon a post by Professor Robert Israel, who suggests calculating an analytic Antiderivative $F$ and then evaluating $F(\gamma(a)) - F(\gamma(b))$, which given the form of my function also seems unrealistic. (After checking for it on Wolfram Alpha)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it isn't a closed curve, then this is just a line integral between the two points $R$ and $-R$, right? So it is correct that the value is $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}(F(-R) - F(R))$, where $F$ is any antiderivative of the integrand.

Comment: Of course, that should be true, however the Antiderivative is $F = \frac{1}{16}\left(-e\text{EI}(iz-1) + \frac{5\text{EI}(iz+3)}{e^3}-\frac{4e^{iz}}{3+iz}\right)$ (calculated with Wolfram) so that's an issue

Comment: If you'd been asked instead to compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ix}dx}{(x-3i)^2(x+i)}$ with a closed semicircular contour, you'd use the fact the arc contribution $\to0$ as $R\to\infty$. Your question is just how to prove that. Would you have otherwise taken it for granted? (By the way, the easiest proof uses the maximum modulus principle.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align} I_R:&= \int\limits_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{(z-3i)^2(z+i)} dz=iR\int\limits_0^\pi \frac{e^{it}e^{iR\cos t} e^{-R\sin t}}{(Re^{it}-3i)^2(Re^{it}+i)} dt, \quad R\gt 3\\
&\Rightarrow\quad 0\le |I_R| \le R \int\limits_0^\pi\left|\frac{e^{-R\sin t}}{(Re^{it}-3i)^2(Re^{it}+i)}      \right|dt\le \frac{\pi}{R^2-6R+9}\\
&\Rightarrow\lim\limits_{R\to \infty}I_R=0 \end{align}$$

The last inequality follows from: $$\begin{align} \text{(a)} \quad & e^{-R \sin t} \le 1 \quad\text{for} \quad 0\le t \le \pi,\\ \text{(b)} \quad &|Re^{it} -3i|^2 = |R\cos t +i(R \sin t-3)|^2\ge R^2-6R+9,\\\text{(c)} \quad& |Re^{it}+i|^2\ge R^2.\end{align}$$

Comment: A bit sobering that this is just an approximation task, didn't even think of that. I don't 100% understand the last inequality, but I can derive that some other time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Florian 1. I have now added an explanation of the last inequality. 2. See it as an advantage that it is not necessary to know the integral for finite $R$ if you need it only in the limit $R\to \infty$!

Comment: @Florian : For estimates like this, you usually just want to find the largest the numerator can be and the smallest the denominator can be

Comment: @Hyperon Thanks a lot, that's really helpful. And yeah, for simplification that is indeed very helpful, but I wish I could just calculate it, sadly that's not possible for most Integrals so I guess you're right

Comment: @MPW That's true, I should take more time to actually learn inequalities, I always stumble over my own brain trying to think of when something is larger or smaller